# Probability of winning a lottery from k = 1 to 10

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I'm 100% stuck on this question, and I have no idea how to even start it. I think I should be using Binomial Random Variables to solve this but I'm not sure if it's right.

The question is:
There are 10 lottery tickets that you scratch to  to see if you win a prize.  4 of the tickets have small cash prizes, the other 6 are worthless.  If X is the number of tickets that you have to scratch off until you have won your first small cash prize, what is P{X=k} for integer values of k from 1 to 10?

My first approach to solving this is:
P{X=1} = (4/10)^1 (Because you get the prize on your first attempt?)
P{X=2} = (4/10)^2 * (6/10)^1

I think this is right can someone confirm, and if it this then I can just follow this pattern up to 10 right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $P(X=1)$, we have $\frac{4}{10}$, since you must choose one of the four winning tickets.

For $P(X=2)$, we need to first choose a losing ticket with probability $\frac{6}{10}$, then we need to choose a winning ticket with probability $\frac{4}{9}$ (since there are $9$ tickets remaining). Then $P(X=2) = \frac{6}{10} \times \frac{4}{9}$.

Similarly, we have $P(X=3) = \frac{6}{10} \times \frac{5}{9} \times \frac{4}{8}$, since you must choose one of the $6$ losing tickets first, then one of the $5$ remaining losing tickets, and then finally choose one of the $4$ winning tickets.

In general, we can see that $P(X=k) = \frac{\frac{6!}{(7-k)!} \times 4}{\frac{10!}{(10-k)!}}$ for $1 \le k \le 7$. This formula is not obvious, but you should see from the $P(X=3)$ and $P(X=2)$ example for how to extend it for $k \ge 4$.

Note that for $X = 8$, $X = 9$, or $X = 10$, the probability is $0$, since there are only $6$ losing tickets.

Comment: Yea I think this makes sense, thanks for the help! I understood it perfectly.